# Encode video for html5 and javascript controlled playback

Tags: video, encoding, webvideos

I want to create something like Apples Mac Pro product page http://www.apple.com/de/mac-pro/ where html5 video playback is being controlled via javascript (by manually setting the currentTime attribute of the video). It works perfectly when I use their video but not at all with my own videos. How can I convert my videos so that they play back nicely?

Using ffmpeg I tried everything I could think of like

- removing the audio track
- decreasing the videos dimensions
- decreasing the framerate
- setting the framerate to 30fps (like in apples video)
- converting their video to jpgs and create a video from those frames (i thought maybe the color-spectrum made a difference (mainly black))
- different options for quality (-crf [18-30] -preset [veryslow-veryfast])
- decreasing the length of the video (apple’s video is 47s long)

I also tried some different options of handbrake but nothing helped.

http://movies.apple.com/media/us/mac-pro/2013/16C1b6b5-1d91-4fef-891e-ff2fc1c1bb58/videos/macpro_main_desktop.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i macpro_main_desktop.mp4
```

shows:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'macpro_main_desktop.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-10-16 22:55:31
  Duration: 00:00:47.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: d kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1120x840, 2797 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-16 22:55:31
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 139 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-16 22:55:31
      handler_name    : hint media handler
```

here is an example of the videos I encoded via ffmpeg:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video-720-main-30fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
  Duration: 00:05:00.49, start: 0.033333, bitrate: 420 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 284 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: I doubt the presence of an audio track or frame size or rate has anything to do with it. Try adding a hint track, like in the Apple video, so "-movflags faststart+rtphint"

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not your HTML or Javasript code? Embedding videos in HTML5 is kinda tricky, especially if you want to control it using custom controls/Javascript

Comment: Hi. @Mulvya thanks for the hint with the hint track. It really helped but playback is still really slow. @ MoritzLost I am quite sure that the video is the problem because when I use apples video I can scrub through without any lag. The code is extremely simple atm. I just update the video's currentTime property on scroll.

Comment: Can you link to your and Apple's videos?

Comment: @Mulvya I added the links.

Comment: First change I would suggest is to encode in main or baseline profile, so try "-profile:v baseline" first. Maybe the fewer reference frames makes a difference.

Comment: Nice. It reacts much faster now. (At least in Chrome and Safari) `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v baseline -movflags faststart+rtphint output.mp4`
Are there any more tweaks that could improve it even more?

Comment: You could add "-x264opts keyint=3:min-keyint=2" to further mimic the Apple file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple video uses a profile with fewer reference frames and also carries a streaming hint track.

The following ffmpeg command template should create a quick seeking MP4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -x264opts keyint=3:min-keyint=2 -{other video encoding parameters} -{audio encoding parameters} -movflags +faststart+rtphint output.mp4
```

Given the profile and GOP sizes set, compression effiency won't be great.

Comment: @gang Did this solve your problem? I tried this but am still stuck with a slow scrub :-(

Comment: Show the full console output of the command you ran. You can upload it to pastebin or the like.

Comment: @bennlich yes this solved my problem.

Comment: @Mulvya thar she blows: http://pastebin.com/tiSDPAVZ

Comment: Add `-r 25`. What I can see is that you have a variable frame rate input with an incorrectly flagged FPS value stored in the container and that's leading FFmpeg to use very large timebase values.

Comment: No luck :-( New output: http://pastebin.com/e9aJpyF1
The very large timebase values you're referring to is what's reported as `tbn`? Also, where do you see the incorrectly flagged FPS stored in the container?

Comment: The `tbr` of your input - that's the stored or assumed framerate. `fps` shown by ffmpeg is total frames / duration. What are you testing the scrub in, and do you have a file that scrubs fast?

Comment: Here's the info on a file that scrubs very quickly: http://pastebin.com/z1WdEYAK. I'm scrubbing in an HTML5 video element, like here: http://codepen.io/gfschultheiss/pen/zvQmPz.

Comment: @Mulvya Also wondering--how does `tbr` affect seeking speed?

Comment: Unless if's very high, it shouldn't. Bitrate matters more.

Comment: Mmm k. Did you notice any clues in the dump from the quickly scrubbing file (http://pastebin.com/z1WdEYAK)? I'm not sure where to look next.